# Как обнулить одномерный массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Вот часть моего кода, он срабатывает по кнопке и делает некоторые вычисления.
Как можно обнулить (очистить) массив, что бы не создавались дополнительные пустые ячейки после повторного нажатия по кнопке. Нужно что бы содержимое обновлялось а не добавлялось повторно.

```js
            vect = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < row; j++) {
                min = matr[0][j]
                for (let i = 0; i < col; i++) {
                    if (matr[i][j] < min)
                    min = matr[i][j];
                }
                vect[n] = min;
                n += 1;
            }
```

Comment: `vect.fill(null);`

Comment: реакт? полный текст задачи бы

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать массив полностью пустым:

```js
vect = [];
```

Для этого также есть [другие интересные варианты](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232046/5308802).

Если нужно сохранить длину массива, то можно пройтись по всем элементам и поставить нулевые значения:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {
    vect[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: `vect = [];`© кажется, вы не видите разницы между заменой новым объектом и обнулением старого.

Comment: @qwabra Со своим опытом очень даже вижу! И тоже подумал об этом написав ответ. Но знаете ли, годы преподавания научили, что порой точность выражений бывает не сильно полезна, например в данном случае – у автора вопроса видимо пробелы в базовом понимании работы кода, и для начала стоит просто научиться решать такие тривиальные задачи, и уже затем понимать подобные нюансы.

Comment: ок, прошу прощения. однако:  ваш ответ не только автор вопроса читать будет ... у меня на англ SO два ответа, (Impact ~92k people reached) . ...

Comment: @qwabra Тоже верно! Но с одной стороны, данный вопрос вряд ли будет как-то популярен, он уже схлопотал и минус, и много голосов на закрытие. Остаётся лишь попытаться помочь конкретно автору. Вообще, по-хорошему автора надо послать в какой-нибудь учебник или онлайн-курс, т.к пробелы в знаниях слишком большие, а мне (да и другим) как-то не интересно отходить от темы и разъяснять основы вроде передачи объектов по ссылке/значению. Проще подзабить и просто дать какой-то работающий ответ. А с другой стороны, для полноты картины здесь есть и другие, более педантичные участники, вроде Вас 

Answer (score 0):

## как очистить массив, и сохранить ссылку на объект ?

- `length = 0` - установить длинну массива = 0
  в большинстве случаев этого может быть достаточно, но лучше с `delete`
- `delete obj[key]` - удалить не только значение но и ключ.
  проверить можно с помощью `Object.keys(obj)`

в примере ниже за очистку массива отвечает ф-я `clearArray(arr)`, остальной код для иллюстрации

```js
const log = arr => console.log(`arr:${JSON.stringify(arr)}`,`length:${arr.length}`)
const genArr = length => Array.from({length}, (q, i) => i)

const arr = genArr(5)

log(arr)

console.log(arr === clearArray(arr))

log(arr)

function clearArray(arr) {
  //--
  arr.forEach((q, i, arr) => {delete arr[i];})
  arr.length = 0
  //--
  return arr;
}
```